# Stuck on Xamarin AAPT error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have just installed Xamarin studio on Windows 8, I create a C# android project, and try to compile it with no luck.

The error I get is on the AAPT tool, but even with verbose output from msbuild all I get is the following in the output window:

```
Task "Aapt"
Aapt Task
  AssetDirectory: 
  ManifestFile: C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Local\Temp\i4va1gur.y4b\AndroidManifest.xml
  ResourceDirectory: obj\Debug\res\
  JavaDesignerOutputDirectory: C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Local\Temp\i4va1gur.y4b
  PackageName: AndroidLocationLogger.AndroidLocationLogger
  UncompressedFileExtensions: 
  ExtraPackages: 
  AdditionalResourceDirectories: 
  LibraryProjectJarsWildcard: obj\Debug\__library_projects__\*.jar
  ExtraArgs: 
C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe package -f -m -M C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Local\Temp\i4va1gur.y4b\AndroidManifest.xml -J C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Local\Temp\i4va1gur.y4b --custom-package androidlocationlogger.androidlocationlogger -F C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Local\Temp\i4va1gur.y4b\resources.apk.bk -S obj\Debug\res -I C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar --auto-add-overlay 
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(707,2): error MSB6006: "aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741816.
Done executing task "Aapt" -- FAILED.
Done building target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" in project "AndroidLocationLogger.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

I really have no idea how to debug this, given how little data it is giving me...

Answer (score 12):

This error mainly occurs due to the name of files in your project,check these first..look also if the names have symbols and spaces...just correct them to free from these types of errors..

Comment: It was the blessed hyphen in the image names. Bless you!

Comment: I had a space in the name of a layout "xxx .xml" !

Comment: This answer solved it for me.  I had a German ä in the name of an image file.

Comment: I didn't have an invalid character per se: I had a folder called values-21 instead of values-v21. (it was missing the "v" before the 21). This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: I created a new project and i see this error. how could it be possible that a new project has such error?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience this is usually come about because of some issue with the Resources (in other words something which has been added to the projects under the Resources Folder  - usually in the Drawable or Layout folder).

If you go into the Resource.Designer.cs file it might provide some clues as to what the issue is with the project.

One possible solution is to remove any of the additional files which you have added to the project and try to rebuild it.

Another method which might work is to Clean the project Build-> Clean Solution and then rebuild the solution.

If you have just started perhaps you could start a new project and then open files from this broken one and copy them over - or just sections of code - and build the project up so that you can diagnose which file is the erroneous one.

Please let me know if this has been of any use to you,

Regards,
James.

Comment: Hi, I am creating a project from scratch and just compiling directly. No new files or anything. The resource directory is untouched!

Answer (score 2):

Resource files added (images, sound etc) should contain only [a-z0-9_.] - I.e no special characters allowed other than '_' and '.',

otherwise you will get this error. "aapt.exe" exited with code 1. (MSB6006)"

Answer (score 2):

Such error also may occur when you have Android build tools installed, which Xamarin does not support. By default Xamarin.Android project prefer the newest version of Android build tools. I had 24.0.0-preview, but it was not supported.
You can provide build tools version manually by adding `AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion` property in your `.csproj` file.
See also: [Xamarin.Android build process](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Packaging_Properties)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve this same issue by deleting bad android.axml files that exist in the layout directory.  If you copy a file and don't rename that file it may exists with invalid file characters that will cause an issue during the build process...

For example:
 "myLayout (copy).axml".

Make sure to rename your layout file correctly, and/or delete them from the project and re-build.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .resx files for localization, make sure you set their "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource"

Answer (score 0):

This error has occurred in two situations for me.

1) if you have bad characters in the file name, at least appt reports an error in the diagnostic output if you look for it. (build->log output = diagnostics)

2) if your layout files, or your menu files reference a resource this is either wrongly spelled or missing. This one takes some hunting. This was the appt error without an diagnostic.

Basically any resource file that is in axml format can reference drawables, and strings, and colours, menus, menu selectors ..etc. open each file one at a time until you find what you reference but what is not there in your resources folders.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the file properties to android asset would do the trick.

Comment: I did the opposite and it worked. Changed the properties fromandroid asset to none.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was a @ in a resource file name that was causing "aapt.exe" exit with an error code, after I renamed the resource file the error got fixed.

Comment: this is a possible solution to the question posted, I edited my question and clarified further

Answer (score -1):

If you have a wrongly done 9 patch you will get this error. I had to mark the expandable patches on all four sides of my image to make the error disappear